# Не могу использовать свой класс в классе стороннего ассета

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хотел модернизировать класс из ассета используя свой класс.

Собственный класс лежит в папке Assets/Scripts

Код ассета лежит в папке Assets/Название ассета. В этой же папке есть asmdef файл. По своему опыту мне кажется что я в этом файле должен указать ссылку на свой класс. Однако я не понимаю как это сделать. В предложенных unity вариантах я его не вижу.

При попытке написания названия своего скрипта в скрипте ассета, visual studia мне его подчеркивает. Но в предложенных вариантах есть только создание скрипта с этим именем в папке ассета.

p.s. Скринов и кода не прилагаю так как полагаю, что это новой информации не принесет. Или я просто не знаю, что следует приложить для лучшего понимания моей проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле asmdef нельязя указывать ссылки на конкретные классы, можно указать ссылки только на другие asmdef. В вашем случае, можете создать для ваших скриптов расширяющих сторонний ассет отдельную папку, переместить туда скрипты, которые вы хотите использовать в стороннем ассете. Далее создать новый asmdef в этой папке (ПМК -> Create -> Assebly Defenition). И чтобы ассет видел ваш скрипт, нужно выбрать его asmdef, в его настройках добавить ссылку - нажать + внизу списка "Assembly Defenition References" и выбрать asmdef, который вы создали в папке со своими скриптами

Comment: Спасибо огромное, мне это помогло!